# Android EditText negative

Tags: android-layout

I am creating an application for calculing fractions. I created 4 EditText to put my numbers, but here the concern is that I can't register negative number, it doesn't take me "-".
How?

Answer (score 0):

In the xml file

```
android:inputType="numberSigned"
```